# Prevent multiple emails in one line in Google Forms using regex

Tags: regex, google-forms

I have a long-form field ("Paragraph" type) in a Google Form. Users are expected to fill in any number of email addresses - at least one email, could be as many as 20-50 email addresses for some users.

I want to make sure that:

1. Each line is likely to be a valid email (by checking for a "@" character and a "." character)
2. Each line contains ONLY ONE email (by checking for "@" characters not separated by line breaks)

I know I can use the following string to check for two valid email addresses separated by a line break:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+\n+[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]
```

However, this limits the user to submitting two (no more, no less) email addresses.

Is there a way to check for 1 email address per line, and allow anything from 1 to multiple emil addresses?

Comment: Try it like this `[\w.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(?:\n+[\w.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)*` See https://regex101.com/r/BrQojZ/1

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately that accepts multiple email addresses per line (e.g. "test@test.com, test2@test2.com" in one line passes the check). I'm hoping to check that users add a line break after each email address.

Comment: Ah, then like this `^[\w.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(?:\n+[\w.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/Y3Qjsk/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the pattern with anchors and repeating 1 or more newlines followed by the same pattern.

```
^[\w.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(?:\n+[\w.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)*$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y3Qjsk/1)